# AngularJS - How to correctly use ng-show inside a ng-repeat? My boolean isn't getting updated

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a ng-repeat that loops over 9 divs, each one has a different color.

When the user clicks on one div, its color it's gonna be the background color of a section.

I'm trying to do this:

The array that gets repeated is structured like this:

```
interface colorBoxes {
    color: string;
    isSelected: boolean;
  }
```

in the view:

```
  <div ng-repeat="s in vm.colorBoxes track by $index">
        <div class="pointer" ng-click="w.backgroundColor = s.color; vm.pickColor(s, $index)" ng-style='{"background-color": s.color}'>
            <i ng-show="vm.isColorSelected($index) === true" class="fa fa-check fa-1x checkOnSelectedLegend"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
```

in the controller:

```
pickColor(array: any, index: number) {
      for(var i = 0; i<=this.colorBoxes.length; i++) {
        this.colorBoxes[i].isSelected = false;
      }
      array[index].isSelected = true;
    }
```

I use this function so when you click on a DIV, its variable: `isSelected` gets true, and all the other DIV's have theirs set to false.

I use this variable in the view with a ng-show, to show a check mark on the DIV that is currently selected, but this isn't working, below the function I put in that ng-show

```
isColorSelected(index:number):boolean {
      return this.colorBoxes[index].isSelected
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

To summarize, I want that when you click on a box, its color string gets applied to another element (that is working correctly with my code), then, that box need to have a check mark appear on top of it, I tried with the above functions, by setting the `isSelected` var to true when clicked, but it doesnt work.

I'm pretty sure the problem is that angular isn't checking for changes in that ng-show, I just don't know exactly how to make it check for changes, and maybe there is a cleaner way to obtain what I'm trying to do!

Thank you

addded fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7zymp2gq/1/

Comment: Why are you using this.colorBoxes in the function instead of vm.colorBoxes?

Comment: added jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7zymp2gq/1/

Comment: @Gobli because in this project we have vm changed to this for the controller, and we use vm only in the view to call stuff in the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here you have your code fixed and working:

http://jsfiddle.net/7zymp2gq/4/

Basically there were 2 things wrong with the function `$scope.pickColor`:

1. The loop was entering into not existing fields, I have changed the `<=` with a `<`
2. It was updating `array[index]`, and it should be updating `$scope.colorBoxes[index]`

Comment: oh boy, that easy uh? what is the difference in using $scope.colorBoxes[index] instead of array[index] ? as I put as argument that array (colorBoxes) anyway, so both versions should be the same? 

and for the loop, rookie mistake, thank you!!

last thing, is this the best approach to my problem? I wasn't sure using a for loop was the best, maybe angular has some methods for what I'm trying to do! thank you anyway, marking your answer as the correct one

Comment: The argument you put was "s", that is a single element of the array, not the entire array, if you want to pass the entire array you should pass "colorBoxes", but I thing it's better this way. 

About the loop, the for is perfectly fine, but if you want to reduce it to one line you could do "$scope.colorBoxes.forEach(function(el){el.isSelected = false;}) "

Comment: The thing that it's a bit ugly is doing ng-show="vm.isColorSelected($index) === true". Because it's not necessary since the ng-show works with booleans, you can do ng-show="vm.isColorSelected($index)"

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer! I change the ng-show and made it cleaner, and thank you for the explanation! I understood now why I couldnt put "s" as argument, because "s" is just the current element of the array that is looping! another rookie mistake :D thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using function at `ng-show` you can use the `isSelected` property:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div class="class1" ng-repeat="s in colorBoxes track by $index">
    <div class="pointer class2" ng-click="pickColor(colorBoxes,$index);" ng-init="lastselected=s.isSelected?$index:null" ng-style='{"background-color": s.color}'>
      <i ng-if="s.isSelected" class="fa fa-check fa-1x checkOnSelectedLegend"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="changeColor" ng-style='{"background-color": chosenColor}'></div>     
</div>
```

[Check this demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/xq4aMe6Xl096ECJ8ouNs?p=preview).